# Getting this error, "Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type '(HttpException) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic')" ,

Tags: flutter, dart, auth0

[image]
Using flutter_auth0 ,  getting the issue when it is directing to auth0 authenticate page for auth0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you have an error handler function somewhere which only accepts an `HttpException` as argument, but a function accepting any object is required because the type system doesn't know that you will only need to catch `HttpException`s.
I can't see from the screenshot where that function comes from, but look for a function with `HttpException` as argument.

(Secondarily, you are eagerly performing three HTTP requests, one POST, one GET and one PATCH request, then you only wait for one of them. You probably need to delay the client requests until you have figured out which one you want. I would either use a switch or a map of functions:

```dart
var handlers = {
  "POST": () => _client.post(...),
  "GET": () => _client.get(...),
  "PATCH": () => _client.patch(...),
};
http.Response response = await handlers[method]();
```

or

```
http.Response response;
switch (method) {
  case "POST": 
   response = await _client.post(...);
   break;
  case "GET": 
   response = await _client.get(...);
   break;
  case "PATCH": 
   response = await _client.patch(...);
   break;
  default:
   throw UnsupportedError("Unknown method: $method");
}
```

)